# JavaScript - How can I iterate object that is actually a map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary, iteration

I got a JSON object from the server that is actually:

```
Map<Integer, Integer>
```

How can I iterate over it and get the key and value in each iteration?

Thanks!

Comment: could you share a sample json object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like that:

```
var key, response = {1:3, 5:6, 3:8}; // sample response of your server
for (key in response) {
    if (response.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log("key: " + key + ", value: " + response[key]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
key: 1, value: 3
key: 3, value: 8
key: 5, value: 6
```

Comment: I didn't understand what is "a".

Comment: Fixed. I have missed a variable renaming.

Answer (score 0):

Once you convert the JSON string to an object you can use a `foreach` style `for` loop

```
for ( var key in map){
  var value = map [key];
  ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's working, but I don't understand why. Each element in the map is a (key,value) pair, so when you iterate over the map, each time you get a pair, so as I see it in your function you do map[pair]. I don't understand how the value extracted from there.

Comment: Iteration over an object in JavaScript is not the same as iterating over a Map in Java... The semantics are completely different.